# Pattern for OO abstract types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, design-patterns

I come from OO languages, and am currently trying to develop an application in Haskell.
I am trying use what would be an abstract class in OO languages, but this does not seem to fit well with Haskell (and probably most functional languages) type system.

In, let's say Java, a minimal code of what I am trying to express would probably look something like this

```
abstract class Transformation {
    public abstract void transform(Image image);
}

class ResizeTransformation extends Transformation {
    public void transform(Image image) {
        // resize the image
    }
}

// some other classes extending Transformation

class Worker {
    public void applyTransformations(Image image, Transformation[] trs) {
        for (Transformation t: trs) {
            t.transform(image);
        }
    }
}

class Parser {
    public Transformation parseTransformation(String rawTransformation) {
        // return ResizeTransformation or some other concrete transformation
    }
}
```

I tried to express this in Haskell with a `Transformation` class, and creating some instances for each transformation, but I get stuck for the Parser, as it does not seem to be possible to return an abstract type.

Here is more or less what my Haskell code looks like now:

```
class Transformation a where
  transform :: Image -> a -> Image

data Resize = Resize
    { newHeight :: Int
    , newWidth  :: Int
    } deriving (Show)


instance Transformation Resize where
    transform image resize = -- resize the image

applyTransformations :: (Transformation a) => Image -> [a] -> Image
applyTransformations image transformations = foldl transform image transformations
```

And I would like to have a function with a signature like this

```
parseTransformation :: (Transformation a) => String -> Maybe a
```

but I do not think it is possible, as returning `Maybe Resize` results in `could not deduce a ~ Resize`, which I can understand.

Am I missing something here, or is what I am trying to do an anti-pattern in Haskell.
If this seems to be a bad approach, I would love to have a hint of what would be a better way to handle such a case in Haskell.

Comment: It looks like you can just make `Transformation` be `Image -> Image`? Then each transform can be constructed from a function taking an extra state required e.g. `resizeTransformation = Int -> Int -> Imgae -> Image`.

Comment: In the FP world, Transformation would be a function. Whenever you see a one-method class in OO, you can immediately translate it to a function in FP.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you! I am going to try refactoring this in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I managed to get the application working,
so I will answer my question describing how I proceeded.

Disclaimer: It is the first time I write a real
world application in Haskell, so I am not sure all these are best practices.

### Single method class/interface

As told in the comments of my question, I used a function for what would have been a single method class or interface in Java.

```
abstract class Transformation {
    public abstract void transform(Image image);
}
```

However, given than I also needed information about the transformation,
I used a record and included a function in it, so instead of

```
class Transformation a where
  transform :: Image -> a -> Image

data Resize = Resize
    { newHeight :: Int
    , newWidth  :: Int
    } deriving (Show)

instance Transformation Resize where
    transform image resize = -- resize the image
```

I ended up with something like

```
type Processor = Image -> Image
data Transformation = Transformation
                      { name      :: String
                      , args      :: String
                      , processor :: Processor
                      }

parseTransformation :: String -> String -> Maybe Transformation
parseProcessor      :: String -> String -> Maybe Processor

resizeProcessor :: ResizeInfo -> Processor
cropProcessor   :: CropInfo -> Processor
```

I parsed the `ResizeInfo` or `CropInfo` in `parseProcessor` depending on the
given transformation name.
So after parsing all the transformations, I get an list of `Transformation`
with everything needed to process the images and keep some info about the
transformations.

### Injected interface

The second issue I got was what could be solved by DI in Java.
Here is a simplified example:

```
public interface Storage {
    public void load(StoredObject o);
    public void save(StoredObject o);
}

public class S3Storage implements Storage {
    // some implementation
}

public class LocalStorage implements Storage {
    // some implementation
}
```

With this definition, I could simply instanciate the storage
depending on a settings file or whatever, and have it injected
in the rest of my application.

Well this is actually not so different of what I ended up doing in Haskell,
and it worked fine.

I used a Storage class defined like this

```
data StoredObject = StoredObject
                  { uniqueId      :: String
                  , content       :: Maybe ByteString
                  } deriving (Show)

class Storage a where
    load :: a -> StoredObject -> IO (Either StorageError StoredObject)
    save :: a -> StoredObject -> IO (Either StorageError ())
```

and then simply created `LocalStorage` and `S3Storage` and wrote a `Storage` instance for each.

```
data LocalStorage = LocalStorage
                  { baseDir :: String
                  }
instance Storage LocalStorage where
    save = -- implementation
    load = -- implementation
```

I changed the functions I used to abstract the used storage with something like this

```
downloadHandler :: (Storage a) => a -> IO ()
downloadHandler storage = -- process download
```

Finally, I simply parsed the configuration when loading the application,
created the storage I wanted based it, and passed it around.
It roughly looks something like this.

```
runApp :: String -> IO ()
runApp "local" = run makeLocalStorage
runApp "s3"    = run makeS3Storage
runApp storage = putStrLn ("no storage named " ++ storage) >> exitFailure

run :: (Storage a) => a -> IO ()
run storage = -- run with my storage
```

With the two above patterns above I managed to get things DRY and extensible enough for now.